# How to create same directory name in elixir?

Tags: filesystems, elixir

I have a directory named "New Item". Now I want to create the same name "New item" but in a different case. How to fix this problem? it impossible to have two different directories called New item and new item

[image]

Comment: From Review: Please be more specific. What exactly is your case? Please EDIT your answer and specify it. Also do not post text inside images, you should copy and paste the text to your question. Please refer too: [HOW TO ASK](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're doing this on a case-insensitive filesystem like the ones in Windows or Mac OS, so `New item`, `new item`, and `New Item` all refer to the same directory. This makes it impossible to have two different directories called `New Item` and `new item`.

Perhaps you want to change the casing of the name? In that case you can use:

```
File.rename("New Item", "new item")
```

Comment: i see.. correct me if im wrong.. this is only happen at Windows or Mac OS ?

Comment: No, it depends on the filesystem. It just happens that macOS and Windows by default use case insensitive filesystem, but you can always use different one.